# 'button_to' and 'link_to' redirect with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have simple application on rails. I need to post some article. My application has devise authorization. In posts_controller.rb `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]`.
On index page was `link_to` and `button_to` with `new_post_path`. If I don't signed in and try `link_to`, I redirected to `/sign_in` page. And if I press `button_to` I redirected on `/posts/new` page, and I see routing error `No route matches [POST] "/posts/new"`.
Tell me please, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your application is behaving exactly as expected.  You have a `before_filter` indicating that a user needs to be authenticated in order to create a new `Post`.  Hence, you are redirected to the sign in page, when you try to `GET /posts/new`.

Assuming you are using resourced routes, the `/posts/new` page will only be provided on `GET` so your attempt to `POST` to it is resulting in an error.

If you want unauthenticated users to be able create posts, change your before filter to

```
before_filter :authenticated_user!, :except => [:show, :index, :new, :create]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I asked the question wrong. I need that `button_to` behaved as `link_to`. If I not signed in and press `button_to` I was redirected to `sign_in` page. How do it?